# Как скрыть кнопку меню в ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-menu

В меню у меня находится постоянно один элемент TextView он должен отображаться постоянно. Как можно скрыть кнопку меню (троеточие) что бы ее нельзя было нажать и открывался пустой список меню!

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/statusTextview"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.TextView"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title=""
        />
</menu>
```

и дальше в коде

**activity.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_learn, menu);
    mTextViewStatus = new TextView(this);

mTextViewStatus.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorWhite));
mTextViewStatus.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
mTextViewStatus.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
mTextViewStatus.setTextSize(12);
menu.add(0, R.id.statusTextview, 1, " ").setActionView(mTextViewStatus).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас онКреатеОптионсМеню в Активити переопределён? Если да то приложите его в вопрос. И если в хмл меню есть его тоже

Comment: Вот здесь вроде бы ответ есть http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692755/how-do-i-hide-a-menu-item-in-the-actionbar

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил код..

Comment: @RedShaman в упор не вижу, не могли бы вы конкретней указать на подходящее решение?

Comment: @RedShaman теперь, кажется, вижу но не уверен что мне подходят, там устанавливается setVisible(false) всем элементам меню, за счет чего скрывается и кнопка, но мне не подходит так как один элемент(TextView )  должен отображаться постоянно.

Comment: Попробуйте предложенным по ссылке выше способом удалять элементы по `id` == `R.id.action_settings` или `R.id.menu_settings`

Answer (score 1):

Решил проблему удалением всех элементов в меню и последующего добавления нужного мне элемента.

Код метода теперь выглядит так:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_learn, menu);
        mTextViewStatus = new TextView(this);
        mTextViewStatus.setText(mWordCounter + " из " + (mWordList.size()));
        mTextViewStatus.setPadding(5, 0, 5, 0);
        mTextViewStatus.setTextAppearance(this, R.style.ActionTextStyle);     

        for (int i = 0; i < menu.size(); i++){
            menu.removeItem(menu.getItem(i).getItemId());
        }

        menu.add(0, R.id.statusTextview, 1, " ").setActionView(mTextViewStatus).setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);   

        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

style.xml

```
<style name="ActionTextStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.TextView"> >
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/text_view_status_font_size</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
</style>
```

Так же: [похожий вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10692755/how-do-i-hide-a-menu-item-in-the-actionbar)

Comment: Свойства, устанавливаемые методами `setTextColor()`, `setTypeface()`, `setPadding()` тоже можно (и нужно) перенести в стиль, раз уж он у вас теперь есть.

Comment: @pavlofff цвет и стиль добавил, а паддинг чет не срабатывает!

Answer (score 0):

Советую вам использовать AppBarLayout, и сделать тему noActionBar